conflict of \counterwithin and cleveref package when sectioncounter is reset
I have a quite long document with different sections and a lots of figures. I reference to them with sectionnumber.figurenumber. Before the appendix I reset the sectioncounter since I want it to be numbered in capitals. If I now try to reference two figures at once (like \cref{fig_a,fig_b}) with one in the main part and one in the appendix they get sorted the wrong way. I tried to build a MWE, which you can see below.
I narrowed it down to a conflict with the \counterwithin command, but if I delete that the figure-numbers get messed up.
\documentclass[paper=A4,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{First chapter}

\section{Second chapter}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:chapter}
\end{figure}

reference to \cref{fig:chapter,fig:appendix}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}} 
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{Appendix}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:appendix}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



No "conflict" there, you are making cleveref's task impossible by tampering with the counter manually this way. Why don't you just use \appendix?

\documentclass[paper=A4,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

% No need for this, \counterwithin already handles that.  In fact, this is
% outright wrong, if the following \counterwithin didn't fix it, you'd have
% wrong references for your appendix labels.
% \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{First chapter}

\section{Second chapter}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:chapter}
\end{figure}

reference to \cref{fig:chapter,fig:appendix}

% You're digging your own grave here... Just use \appendix instead.
% \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
% \setcounter{section}{0}

\appendix

\section{Appendix}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:appendix}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



how embarrassing. I always wondered what the \appendix does... Never thought of that and just tried to build for myself what I wanted to achieve. Thanks a lot for the help, this obviously fixes my problem.
